# Sass: Setting global variables based on theme

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to set global variables when a theme mixin is included since it seems much more straight-forward to use than this "[themify](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1)" stuff I find from searching.

The idea is something like having a `_themes.scss` with

```
@mixin light-theme { $primary-color: #123456 !global; }
@mixin dark-theme { $primary-color: #654321 !global; }

body.light-theme { @include light-theme }
body.dark-theme { @include dark-theme }
```

The problem is it always uses the dark-theme value since it is declared last. Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: What is the class of the HTML body element?

Comment: `light-theme`, but it can change dynamically.

Comment: I think what you have shown should work - there must be more to make it not work.